How can I minimize condensation on the windows?
With the winter months here, I get condensation on my windows where the internal grilles are. I'm assuming because these are metal and colder, the change in temp draws the condensation there. Any advice on how to minimize condensation on the windows? I have a dehumidifier. I also have Bali venetian blinds. Not sure if turning them up or down would make a difference? Placement of dehumidifier? Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Here is the window type. Double hung. Condensation occurs where the internal grates are.

When heat contacts a cold surface you get condensation. Probably have heat coming from you vents near the window. Maybe it could be redirected. Pictures would help us to give you a good answer.

Are these double pane windows or old double hungs with a storm window?

If you're getting condensation inside the window—between the panes where the grilles are—you have a broken seal and they're no longer insulated.

@Huesmann: This is incorrect. Humidity between the glass is an indication that the silica gel used in the sealed unit is saturated and can no longer remove humidity entering the unit. This does not change the insulating properties of the sealed unit.

@DelphicOracle how does (new) humidity come in between the panes without the—insulating—noble gas that previously filled the space between panes leaking out?

Noble gases increase the insulating value of the sealed unit. The initial insulating value (R2) of the sealed unit is created by the air space. Argon increases it to R3. Krypton increases it to around R4. Even if the seal is broken, the sealed unit performs better than a single piece of glass.

You are getting condensation on the inside glass surface where the grills are located:
The grills are colder than the surrounding air pockets created by the grills, cooling the inside surface of the glass and allowing condensation to form.
In addition to the advice offered by SteveSh, you should also try keeping the blinds up to allow at least convection across the glass surface. Moving air does not allow condensation to form.
You could also install a plastic film on the inside to control the amount of humidified air reaching the window. Since the window probably has a relatively high air leakage rate anyway, this will balance the humidity level with the exterior and reduce condensation while maintaining your interior humidity level.
The long term solution is to replace the sealed units with ones that do not have grills and have a Low-E coating on the inside surface. This increases the surface temperature of the inside pane, increasing the level of humidity needed to allow condensation to form.

To minimize condensation on a window (or any surface for that matter), you have two choices:

Increase the temperature of the surface, or
Reduce the amount of moisture in the air.  That is, lower the relative humidity.

If your indoor temperature is 70 deg F, and the relative humidity is 50%, the dew point temperature is 52 deg F.
Under these conditions, any surface that is at 52 deg F (or lower) is going to have moisture condense on.
Note that most homes tend to be on the dry side (low relative humidity) in the winter time, due to heating, which is the reason humidifiers are used to increase the rel humidity in the home.  Too low a rel humidity can allow shocks from static electricity and dry out wood in furniture.
